# why is vuex store only available after setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, vuex

I have a lib which imports the vuex store

```
import {store} from "./index"
```

and that `index` file has an constant export like

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({ ...
```

in the file I'm doing the import, I wanted to use something from the store after the import, but `store` was undefined.

if I wrapped my store access in a setTimeout like

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  // use store normally now..
},0)
```

it works.

Why? I'm guessing this isn't specific to Vuex but I don't know why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a case of circular dependency.
Circular dependencies compile in webpack, but you get bugs at runtime.

Assuming you have files `A` and `B` and the dep chain is like `A -> B -> A`, then when `B` tries to import `A`, it still hasn't got to `export` stuff (because `import` statements precede statements that aren't `import` statements).

So `import default ./A` from `B` immediately returns `undefined`.

So either: make the `B` export a function that is somehow called after the `A` export is called, or create a module `C` that both `A` and `B` depend on that somehow fixes this circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are loading things out of order or your setup is a little off.

I would try injecting the store into your Vue instance, then you can assume it will be available in all sub components.

`main.js`

```
import {store} from "./index"

new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Now in any child components you will have access to your store via `this.$store`